# Como converter uma String Char, armazenando em um vetor de Inteiro em C?

Tags: c

Como converter uma String Char e adicionar em um vetor de Inteiro?

Comment: Quer converter uma `String` em `int` e guardar esse `int` num vetor de `ints` é isso ?

Comment: Seja mais claro na pergunta por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente o que você deve fazer é uma técnica conhecida como casting, casting server para você dizer ao computador que certo tipo de dado deve ser interpretado como o dado que você está fazendo casting, colocando em outras palavras você força que um dado do tipo A seja interpretado pelo computador como um dado do tipo B.

Para fazer casting é bem simples, basta você indicar o dado que você deseja que ele seja interpretado na frente da variável que você deseja, é muito importante que você coloque ambos o tipo e a variável entre parênteses, para evitar que o interpretador interprete errado, um exemplo, vamos supor que você tem um dado do tipo `float` em uma variável chamada `X` e você deseja atribuir esse dado a uma variável `B`, só que como um inteiro, para fazer isso basta fazer o casting, então a resposta sairia de tal maneira `B = (int)(X);`.

Para facilitar o seu entendimento recomendarei aqui um [vídeo do youtube](https://youtu.be/jG_Pp_Cozwc) que ensina a fazer casting, e também um [artigozinho do IME (USP)](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/algoritmos/aulas/footnotes/cast.html) sobre o assunto.

Indo direto à resposta da sua pergunta, mas recomendo que antes disso você veja o vídeo e o artigo, e também que pratique / tente fazer sozinho, mas sem mas delongas aqui está a resposta da sua pergunta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main ()
{
    char strVar[] = "ABCabc";
    int vet[10];
    register int i;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    for ( i = 0; strVar[i] != '\0'; ++i )
        vet[i] = (int)(strVar[i]);

    printf("O que há escrito na string: %s.\n"
           "Seus respectivos em inteiro (tabela ASCII):\n", strVar);
    for ( i = 0; strVar[i] != '\0'; ++i )
        printf("%i = %c\n", vet[i], vet[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Uma pequena dica, sempre quando fazer um post aqui no stcak overflow seja bem especifico com o que você deseja, além disso é muito interessante que você mostre o que conseguiu fazer até o momento, para nós conseguirmos dizer onde está exatamente o seu erro, e também darmos uma melhor resposta à sua pergunta, também mostrar os output que esta dando, possíveis mensagens de erro ou warnigs e etc.

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte com o aprendizado dá linguagem C bro :).

Comment: Embora eu reconheça eu seu esforço e mérito em responder à pergunta a mesma é quase impossível de responder acertadamente, pois não está clara de todo. Leia o meu comentário na pergunta e veja como eu interpreto a questão de uma forma totalmente diferente, como se fosse uma conversão de um `char*` para `int` manualmente ou com `atoi`. Nestes casos acho melhor não responder até que seja clara a intenção do Autor da Pergunta.

Comment: Faz sentido, e você tem razão, o sentido da pergunta dele ficou ambíguo mesmo, deveria ter esperado alguma confirmação, mas de qualquer forma obrigado pela dica.